# Query SharePoint List Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm trying to obtain values from a SharePoint 2010 list. The List name is "SitesList" at the URL of "servername/sites/dev/Lists/SitesList/AllItems.aspx". The Columns that I would like to print on the alert message "Title" and "URL."

Once I run everything, the page loads but nothing happens at all. I can see that my web part is there and I even switched out the code to something simple like an alert message and it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var siteUrl = '/sites/dev/';

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('SitesList');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>" + "<Value     Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>");
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,     this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +
        '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') +
        '\nURL: ' + oListItem.get_item('URL');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're never actually triggering the `retrieveListItems` function.

Try adding this at the top of you script, after the `var siteUrl`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var siteUrl = '/sites/dev/';

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

function retrieveListItems() {
...
}
...
</script>
```

This is SharePoint specific and will wait for SP.JS to load before executing the retrieveListItems function.

This is typically a more recommended approach than jQuery's document.ready function, or native JS's self executing functions as many things happen behind the scenes with SharePoint apps after the page loads.

Hope this helps!